# Format Oracle number (YYYYMMDD) to SAS date9 using a pass-through query

Tags: oracle, sas, format, pass-through

How can I convert a date stored as a number (length 8, format 20.) from Oracle (YYYYMMDD) to a **SAS** `date9` format within a pass-through query?

I tried `to_char(f_date)` and `to_date(to_char(f_date),'YYYYMMDD')`

But I don't know how to apply the SAS format (date9.) within the passthough query now

Comment: I know nothing about SAS. Presuming you have today's date in format you specified, YYYYMMDD: 20221130. What would then SAS date9 format be? In other words, what result do you expect?

Comment: 20221130 is formatted to 30OCT2022 (FORMAT=DATE9. in SAS) 
(It's stored in SAS as numeric with a formatting).
SAS has only two data types: real numbers and fixed length character strings and uses formats and informats.

Comment: "a date as a number" - it's unclear, what data type if the `f_date` column in your Oracle table? Is it actually a date, or are you storing dates as number for some reason?

Comment: @AlexPoole The date is stored as number in Oracle (Numeric, length 8, format 20.) 
It's not my choice :-(

Comment: So you have a number like 20,221,130 in a field in Oracle and when it gets to SAS you want it to be a DATE?  You cannot do that directly.  You will need to convert it to a date on either the SAS or the Oracle side.

Comment: @Tom The number in Oracle is like `20221130`

Comment: 20221130 and 20,221,130 represent the same actual number.  Adding the commas for humans just makes it more obvious that you are talking about a number and not a date.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented:

- if you pass `20221130`
- you want to get `30NOV2022`

then

```
SQL> select to_char (to_date ('20221130', 'yyyymmdd'), 'ddMONyyyy', 'nls_date_language=english') result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
---------
30NOV2022

SQL>
```

Comment: The result is `30NOV2022` but in SAS the data type is `string` and not formatted as `date9.` For plain SQL this works, but not for SAS.

Comment: @JohnDoe - then should the pass-through part just treat it as a native date, and not try to format it at all?

Comment: @AlexPoole It is quite possible that what I want is not possible at all using a pass-through.

Answer (score 0):

If `f_date` is a date then you can just convert it to a string in the format you want:

```
to_char(f_date, 'DDMONYYYY', 'nls_date_language=english')
```

If it is a number - which it shouldn't be - then you'll need to convert that to a date first:

```
to_char(to_date(to_char(f_date), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DDMONYYYY', 'nls_date_language=english')
```

In both cases I've included the optional third argument to `to_char()` to force the month abbreviation to English regardless of the users session settings.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qQd8AwPi)

Answer (score 0):

On the Oracle side you can convert it to a DATE value using TO_DATE() function.  You might need to first convert number to a string using the TO_CHAR() function.

From the SAS side you should then see a DATE value.  If you instead see it as DATETIME value then you could try using the DBSASTYPE= dataset option to tell SAS that you would like the variable created as DATE type values (number of days) instead of DATETIME type values (number of seconds).  Or use the DATEPART() function to convert it to date value on the SAS side

If you pull it across as a number as you describe (that is today's date of 30NOV2022 would be the number 20,221,130) then you can convert it to date values on the SAS side using INPUT() and PUT() functions.

```
date = input(put(date,z8.),yymmdd8.);
```

Once you have it as date values on the SAS side you can attach any of the many SAS formats that know how to display date values in ways that humans can understand.  Such as the DATE9. format.

Comment: The number in Oracle is like `20221130`. Formatting seems not working in SAS when using a passthrough query. Can't use `put` or `input`

Comment: In the passthrough part you need to use the Oracle functions (to_date,to_char,etc).